# JavaScript - Adding span to children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I got a code which should add span, if it doesn't exist on children, but at the moment it adds to only one and not to others, because "code" sees it already exists. How to do it, that if there will be new div, then it adds to that as well?

```
    if($("#itemcart div").children().length > 0){

    } else{
        $("#itemcart div").append($("<span> X</span>"));
    }
```

Comment: `there will be new div` - what do you mean?

Comment: If you click on "item card" then it makes div for it under the #itemcart and then it should also append that X. It does it for first one, but not for other div's what will be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if i understood, anyway, assuming you have multiple div and you want to check if EVERY div has a child span you can do something like this:

```
$("#itemcart div").each(function(){
    if( $(this).children().length > 0){

    } else{
        $(this).append($("<span> X</span>"));
    }
});
```

This will iterate through every div. In this loop, you can use *this* to refers to the current *div* and check if it has or not a children *span*

See the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3qkpLnd9/1/

Comment: If I may ask, maybe you could help me out. I got code, if you click X it will remove it, but I would like to add there one "addition" if you click X it will remove it and does also removeClass where id matches variable. This is how this removing code looks like: `  $("#itemcart span").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().remove()
  });` if I at the moment add there removeClass then it will remove that from all items which are selected, but I need it to remove that class from that where id name is same as span name/matches variable.

Comment: @JacobSeen yes, you could use a [data attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) to store ID you want to update, something like `<div data-update="#box1">1: <span> X</span> </div>`, then, before removing the element you retrieve this attribute, and use it as selector to removeClass. I updated the fiddle as example: https://jsfiddle.net/3qkpLnd9/3/ (or if you want to share your code, i can look at it).

Answer (score 1):

You need a correct [Selector](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=selector):

```
var spanLength = $("#itemcart div span").length;
if(spanLength > 0){
   $("#itemcart div").append($("<span> "+(spanLength+1)+"</span>"));
} else{
    $("#itemcart div").append($("<span> 1</span>"));
}
```

Comment: Still it adds only to one that X

Comment: can you add your html as well?

Answer (score 0):

check this code. Just edit it with your selectors, and it is ready to use:

```
$('p.click').on('click', function () {

   var newDiv = document.createElement('div'), 
   span = document.createElement('span');

   span.innerText = 'X';

   newDiv.appendChild(span);

    $('.container').append($(newDiv));
});
```

and real fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nx1fuffc/